# Hide a pie-part of a square/rectangle div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So lets say i have a div 100px width and height and i would like to hide just a part of it using CSS/HTML/JS And this part should be a part of a pie like a pizza triangle. Here is an example: [image]

So i want to cut a part of it like it would be a circle having a coordinates of a middle point and a start/end angle of cut part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with a `SVG` shape, using a [polygon](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/shapes.html#PolygonElement) or with some CSS transformations but without real transparency (as in your image).

Example on codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLdez/

---

**Markup for SVG solution**

```
<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

  <desc>Square without a pizza slice</desc>
  <polygon fill="cyan" points="0,0 0,100 100,100, 100,30, 50,50 70,0" />

</svg>
```

---

**Style for CSS solution**

```
div { 
  background: cyan;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px; height: 100px; 
  position: relative; 
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;  
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-42deg) translate3d(30px, -60px, 0) rotateZ(-25deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-42deg) translate3d(30px, -60px, 0) rotateZ(-25deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-42deg) translate3d(30px, -60px, 0) rotateZ(-25deg);
  transform: skew(-42deg) translate3d(30px, -60px, 0) rotateZ(-25deg);
}
```

---

Resulting screenshot

[image]

Using transformations all edges are still smooth, but with this approach you need to calculate by hand the values of `skew` and `rotate` instead of passing a list of coordinates — as in the SVG approach  — and you need to also specify the exact `background-color` for the pseudoelement.

Comment: It could be also easily done with `canvas` too but I think the exact problem is that there is a `div`

Comment: I think it's quite impossible to obtain that shape (especially with transparent background on the missing part) with only a div. Maybe with a nested element, working on pseudoelements and rotations it could be possible but it would be really tricky

Comment: Actually it can be canvas too, but what if i also want that slice to be bigger than 90 degrees? For example i want to show only 30deg of an image, so 330deg has to be transparent

Comment: simply change the points so as to draw an "inverse" slice: `points="70,0 50,50 100,30"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CSS :after` and `transform` to position a triangle over the right corner.

### HTML

```
<div class="sqaure"></div>
```

### CSS

```
.sqaure {
    position: relative;
    background: cyan;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.sqaure:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: -40px;
    content:"";
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    border-top: 90px solid white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xDre6/1/)

Comment: This just works on a solid background (in this case, the background is white), it's not truly clipped and can't work if the background is an image http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/xDre6/2/